# Browser "back button" reload Yammer App but does not go to previous page SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: office365, yammer, sharepoint-online

I have SharePoint 2013 Online website. I added Yammer App to site collection. Then I added Yammer web part to home page. So now whenever I click the "back button" in browser ONCE - instead of going back to previous page - it is reloading Yammer web part and stay on the same page.
If I click the "back button" TWICE "quickly" it send me to the previous browser page.
Did anyone have the same issue? And may be find the way to resolve it? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This problem was discussed with Microsoft Yammer dev team and they admitted that this is another bug they will need to fix. So by the time you read this post may be it is already fixed. But if not, here is the work around for those who will have the same issue:

First of all instead of installing Yammer App to site collection you should just go to Yammer group of your company and grab the embedded code, which you can add to the page using "Script Editor" web part. Here is a good step by step instructions on how to do that including additional useful settings: https://developer.yammer.com/connect/

Cheers!